# TFS for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to work on my ASP.NET Projects.

Currently, I am trying to add my projects to Source Control preferably Team Foundation Server.

Installed TFS 2015 on a server and tried connecting from Visual studio 2012 to add a team project, which is not successful. Please let me know which version of tfs is compatible with VS2012 and details would be appreciated.

I was trying to get TFS 2012 but I got a response from the technical support that 'Based on the search results, the only versions available on the VLSC site are 2013 and 2015.' The techical support person from my workplace was trying to download TFS 2012 as per my request for me to work on the set up.

Please provide any help links available.I haven't done anything on the admin side and this confuses me a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not successful"? Are you getting an error message? Visual Studio 2012 should work just fine with TFS 2012.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, Daniel!

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I now have TFS 2015 on a server and while trying to add a team project from VS2012; File->New Team Project- getting the error 'TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permissions or with an older version of team explorer. Contact your project administrator to check your permissions or to determine how to upgrade Team Explorer'.    When i click on the help link i am redirected to the web page https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Pcw.EngineStarter.NoPermission.Error)&rd=true

Comment: I have admin rights everywhere except 'Windows Sharepoint Services' which we do not have in our institution. So I am trying to connect to TFS 2015 from VS2012 which is not successful yet.  The below answer says it should work with latest visual studio 2012 update which i already have and still having the same problem while trying to add a team project. I have not tried yet connecting to TFS2012 from VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2015 requires latest Visual Studio 2012 update. Supports Git with Visual Studio Tools for Git extension.

Check TFS requirements and compatibility at website below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/requirements

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you're trying to create a new **team** project in TFS 2015.

In order to create a Team Project, you need to be using the same version of Visual Studio as you're using TFS. So, to create a team project in TFS 2015, you need to use Visual Studio 2015. This can be done from VS2015 Community or Team Explorer 2015.